# What is the "make -jX" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, makefile

Say you had a graph representing the dependencies defined in a make file.  What is the (an?) algorithm that is used to determine in what order dependencies should be built and what is parallelizable (when using the -jX flag).

E.g. if you had the following deps:

```
A: B C
B: D
C: D
D:
```

'D' clearly needs to be built first, but once it is built, B and C can be built in parallel, and when they both complete, A can be built.

Comment: See [Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), where  “vertices of the graph may represent tasks to be performed, and the edges may represent constraints that one task must be performed before another”

Comment: @jwpat7: I guess the real question is how the vertices are assigned to threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can see precisely the algorithm that make uses by using `make -d` to print debugging information.  For your example (I added `echo` commands to actually cause something to happen):

```
$ make -r -d -j
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `A'.
 File `A' does not exist.
  Considering target file `B'.
   File `B' does not exist.
    Considering target file `D'.
     File `D' does not exist.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `D'.
    Must remake target `D'.
Putting child 0x7fdae2c08110 (D) PID 71724 on the chain.
    Commands of `D' are being run.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `B'.
  The prerequisites of `B' are being made.
  Considering target file `C'.
   File `C' does not exist.
    Pruning file `D'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `C'.
  The prerequisites of `C' are being made.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `A'.
The prerequisites of `A' are being made.
Live child 0x7fdae2c08110 (D) PID 71724 
D
Reaping winning child 0x7fdae2c08110 PID 71724 
Removing child 0x7fdae2c08110 PID 71724 from chain.
Considering target file `A'.
 File `A' does not exist.
  Considering target file `B'.
   File `B' does not exist.
    Considering target file `D'.
    File `D' was considered already.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `B'.
  Must remake target `B'.
Putting child 0x7fdae2c083c0 (B) PID 71729 on the chain.
  Commands of `B' are being run.
  Considering target file `C'.
   File `C' does not exist.
    Pruning file `D'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `C'.
  Must remake target `C'.
Live child 0x7fdae2c083c0 (B) PID 71729 
Putting child 0x7fdae2c09020 (C) PID 71734 on the chain.
  Commands of `C' are being run.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `A'.
The prerequisites of `A' are being made.
Live child 0x7fdae2c09020 (C) PID 71734 
Live child 0x7fdae2c083c0 (B) PID 71729 
B
Reaping winning child 0x7fdae2c083c0 PID 71729 
Removing child 0x7fdae2c083c0 PID 71729 from chain.
Live child 0x7fdae2c09020 (C) PID 71734 
Considering target file `A'.
 File `A' does not exist.
  Considering target file `B'.
  File `B' was considered already.
  Considering target file `C'.
  Still updating file `C'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `A'.
The prerequisites of `A' are being made.
Live child 0x7fdae2c09020 (C) PID 71734 
C
Reaping winning child 0x7fdae2c09020 PID 71734 
Removing child 0x7fdae2c09020 PID 71734 from chain.
Considering target file `A'.
 File `A' does not exist.
  Considering target file `B'.
  File `B' was considered already.
  Considering target file `C'.
  File `C' was considered already.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `A'.
Must remake target `A'.
Putting child 0x7fdae2c090c0 (A) PID 71739 on the chain.
Commands of `A' are being run.
Live child 0x7fdae2c090c0 (A) PID 71739 
A
Reaping winning child 0x7fdae2c090c0 PID 71739 
Removing child 0x7fdae2c090c0 PID 71739 from chain.
Considering target file `A'.
File `A' was considered already.
```

Notice these two lines together:

```
Live child 0x7fdae2c09020 (C) PID 71734 
Live child 0x7fdae2c083c0 (B) PID 71729
```

Showing both `B` and `C` recipes running at the same time.